# Calculating difference of successive column values group by another column

Tags: r, dplyr

Following are the first 4 rows of my data frame. I have data for US states. So I have 4 records for each state i.e. yearly emission measurement for 4 years

```
states_fp  year total_emissions
(chr) (int)           (dbl)
2        01  1999       25226.298
3        01  2002       22883.223
4        01  2005       23855.563
5        01  2008        2803.835
```

I want to add a column that contains the delta. i.e difference from previous year.

```
states_fp  year total_emissions    difference
(chr) (int)           (dbl)
2        01  1999       25226.298   0
3        01  2002       22883.223   -2343.075
4        01  2005       23855.563   972.34
5        01  2008        2803.835   -21051.728
```

I would love a dplyr solution.

```
states_fp  year total_emissions
(chr) (int)           (dbl)
1         01  1999      25226.2980
2         01  2002      22883.2235
3         01  2005      23855.5635
4         01  2008       2803.8350
5         02  1999       1179.7820
6         02  2002       1256.3100
7         02  2005        871.3000
8         02  2008        200.1777
9         04  1999       6358.7810
10        04  2002       7020.6206
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just add a new column in like this?

```
DF$difference <- append(diff(DF$total_emissions, lag = 1, differences = 1), 0, after = 0)
```

No need for dplyr

Here is a short variant:

```
DF$difference <- c(0, diff(DF$total_emissions))
```

In most cases it is better to have `NA` for the first difference. This normaly prevents to calculate later something strange. If you want that use: `c(NA, diff(...))`

For doing that for every state:

```
my.diff <- function(x) c(0, diff(x))
DF$difference <- ave(DF$total_emissions, DF$states_fp, FUN=my.diff)
```

(tested with other data and with your new data)

Comment: I need to do it for every state. i.e. 1999 for every state should be zero..

I can tweak afterwards by setting all 1999 rows to zero but I want to learn how to do that...

Comment: 1. make a function from the answer. 2. use `ave(DF$total_emissions, DF$state_fp, FUN=...)`

Comment: I get this error when I try 

Error in split.default(x, g) : group length is 0 but data length > 0

Comment: For me this works: `my.diff <- function(x) c(0, diff(x));
DF <- iris;
DF$difference <- ave(DF$Sepal.Length, DF$Species, FUN=my.diff)`

Comment: `DF$difference <- ave(DF$total_emissions, DF$states_fp, FUN=my.diff)` it was a typo